# join columns of data frame into one

Tags: r, join, dataframe

I have a data frame with multiple columns, such as the example:

```
          V1         V2         V3         V4
1 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890
```

I want to join all columns into one. The number of columns in the dataframe can vary, is there any way to make a union without having to subsets?

In this case, I want to have this result:

```
TAGS_LIST 
1234567890 
1234567890 
1234567890 
1234567890
```

Comment: Provide a reasonably small dataset with `dput()`?  We can show you how best then, but this is very possible.

Comment: Accordingly to your example what you need is to transpose that data.frame, try using `t(dat)`

Comment: yes! did not know t (). It works, but now I have to delete the first column. How could it?

Comment: Deleting the first column after you transpose is the same as deleting the data, according to your example.

Comment: is true, I have made ​​a mistake when i looking at the data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply transpose the data frame.  This will coerce it to class "matrix".
However, we can re-class it by wrapping the transposition with `data.frame`.

```
> d
          V1         V2         V3         V4
1 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890

> d2 <- data.frame(t(d))
> names(d2) <- "TAGS_LIST"
> d2
    TAGS_LIST
V1 1234567890
V2 1234567890
V3 1234567890
V4 1234567890

> class(d2)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: Presumably he has more than one row but I don't know.